# Recursive method to determine if a string is a hex number - Java

Tags: java, methods, recursion, hex

This is a homework question that I am having a bit of trouble with.

Write a recursive method that determines if a String is a hex number.
Write javadocs for your method.
A String is a hex number if each and every character is either 
0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 
or a or A or b or B or c or C or d or D or e or E or f or f.

At the moment all I can see to test this is if the character at 0 of the string is one of these values he gave me then that part of it is a hex.

Any hints or suggestions to help me out?

This is what I have so far: `

```
public boolean isHex(String string){


    if (string.charAt(0)==//what goes here?){
        //call isHex again on s.substring(1)
    }else return false;
    }
```

`

Comment: You're on the right track.  Look up String.substring and think about how to set up a recursive check of all the characters in the string.

Comment: Please post your code and we can see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @sverre I had something similar to this in uni (didn't we all?) and my TA tried to tell me my method was poor because it used `String.substring()` explaining that it made my method `O(n^2)`. I took it up with the professor (with the String class source code to prove my case.) Let's hope Joel's TA isn't so naive! :-)

Comment: @glowcoder: And I don't see how the TA would've been wrong. string.substring() creates a new string except if the result would be the original string. So since your method would be called n times and would copy O(n) chars each, that makes for O(n*n).

Comment: @Voo that's the mistake he made. In Java, `substring` is O(1). It doesn't copy chars. The resulting string uses the same underlying `char[]`. All it changes are the start and offset pointers (actually not pointers, just `int`s specifying the index.)

Comment: @Glowcoder Thinking about it (and looking at the correct constructor) shows that you're right ;) Ah immutable strings make really for much easier problems. Though I'd still go with the start/end index version, just because that's the more common concept - but in the end it'll be the same.

Comment: @Voo they absolutely do. This is one great advantage, as well as thread safety. It's really a lesson they should be teaching early.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since this is homework, I only give some hints instead of code:

Write a method that always tests the first character of a String if it fulfills the requirements. If not, return false, if yes, call the method again with the same String, but the first character missing. If it is only 1 character left and it is also a hex character then return true.

Pseudocode:

```
public boolean isHex(String testString) {


   If String has 0 characters -> return true;

   Else

      If first character is a hex character -> call isHex with the remaining characters

      Else if the first character is not a hex character -> return false;

}
```

Comment: I was able to get this far in my code but what I am having trouble is in this part right here.  "If first character is a hex character" do I have to create something like this if(s.charAt(0)=='A') call isHex again but do I have to do that for A-F and from 0-9?

Comment: The simplest way to test is is maybe: if (s.subString(0,1).equals("A") || s.subString(0,1).equals("B") .... )

Comment: Oh ok. I was trying to avoid that but I guess I have to do it that way.

Comment: @Joel See my answer for a better way to check for hexDigit. I thought you were looking for an outline to check for hexString.

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a good hex digit method:

```
boolean isHexDigit(char c) {
    return Character.isDigit(c) || (Character.toUpperCase(c) >= 'A' && Character.toUpperCase(c) <= 'F');
}
```

Hints or suggestions, as requested:

1. All recursive methods call themselves with a different input (well, hopefully a different input!)
2. All recursive methods have a stop condition.

Your method signature should look something like this

```
boolean isHexString(String s) {
    // base case here - an if condition

    // logic and recursion - a return value

}
```

Also, don't forget that hex strings can start with "0x". This might be (more) difficult to do, so I would get the regular function working first. If you tackle it later, try to keep in mind that 0xABCD0x123 shouldn't pass. :-)

About substring: Straight from the String class source:

```
public String substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex) {
if (beginIndex < 0) {
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(beginIndex);
}
if (endIndex > count) {
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex);
}
if (beginIndex > endIndex) {
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(endIndex - beginIndex);
}
return ((beginIndex == 0) && (endIndex == count)) ? this :
    new String(offset + beginIndex, endIndex - beginIndex, value);
}
```

offset is a member variable of type `int`

value is a member variable of type `char[]`

and the constructor it calls is

```
String(int offset, int count, char value[]) {
this.value = value;
this.offset = offset;
this.count = count;
}
```

It's clearly an O(1) method, calling an O(1) constructor. It can do this because String is immutable. You can't change the value of a String, only create a new one. (Let's leave out things like reflection and `sun.misc.unsafe` since they are extraneous solutions!) Since it can't be changed, you also don't have to worry about some other Thread messing with it, so it's perfectly fine to pass around like the village bicycle.

Comment: @ikegami consider passing in `0xx123`. Not a valid hex string. Neither is `1230x456`. But, since `0x456` is, and assuming your algorithm passes that test, when you had trimed the `123` off, you'd be left with `0x456` but you would want to return false. It is a (slightly) more challenging problem, but it is still a problem.

Comment: Yep saw your comment above and already deleted the wrong first comment. I stay corrected :)

Answer (score 1):

When solving problems recursively, you generally want to solve a small part (the 'base case'), and then recurse on the rest.

You've figured out the base case - checking if a single character is hex or not.

Now you need to 'recurse on the rest'.

Here's some pseudocode (Python-ish) for reversing a string - hopefully you will see how similar methods can be applied to your problem (indeed, all recursive problems)

```
def ReverseString(str):
    # base case (simple)
    if len(str) <= 1:
        return str

    # recurse on the rest...
    return last_char(str) + ReverseString(all_but_last_char(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should recursively iterate the characters in string and return the boolean AND of whether or not the current character is in `[0-9A-Fa-f]` with the recursive call...

Answer (score 0):

You have already received lots of useful answers. In case you want to train your recursive skills (and Java skills in general) a bit more I can recommend you to visit [Coding Bat](http://codingbat.com/java). You will find a lot of exercises together with automated tests.